# Primefaces Datatable JSF2.0

Tags: xhtml, jsf-2, datatable, primefaces

Well Ive been developing a JSF interface, and using primefaces have managed to create two datatables which pull data from an SAP / oracle ondemand crm system. However all is not going so smooth, Im having trouble with the datatable in a number of area's.

1. I cannot seem to assign command buttons with unique ID's if I add them within a column in the datatable (cant use rowindexvar as it cannot be used for processing). Basically I need to set two buttons insert & Update as invisible until a row is selected in the second datatable in which time the button for the related table in the above datatable is then enabled and becomes clickable.
2. I cannot seem to get the highlight color of the rowselect to change its colour, it maintains a weird yellow indentation color, which isnt strong enough to really let the user know they have selected the row.
3. When I zoom in on the datatable, the columns overflow out of the datatable, (due to the number of columns) and i really really cannot find a work around.

All of these problems ive searched extensively to no avail so Im hoping that some1 here maybe even "Cagatay Civici" can try help me in some regard, I would really really appreciate the help.

Heres my XHTML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <p:themeSwitcher initialText="Change Skin"  buttonPreText="Skin: "/>   
        <title>Elpone Facelet</title>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            td{ font-family:sans-serif; font-size: 10px;}
            h{ font-family:sans-serif; font-size: 10px; font-weight: bold;}
            body{background-color: grey;}
            #bannerImage{width:100%; height:160px;}
            .ui-datatable .ui-state-highlight {
            background-color:#83AAB4;}
           #buttonPanel{visibility:hidden;} 



        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body >
        <div id="bannerContainer">
        <h:graphicImage id="bannerImage" alt="ban_eloma" url="/resources/Eloma_banner1.jpg"/> 
        </div>

      <h:form>
                <p:panel header="SAP Accounts" id="sapPanel">    

            <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />            

            <p:dataTable style="width:101%;"
                scrollable="false"    
                rowIndexVar="rowID"   
                id="debTable"
                var="debitors" 
                value="#{tableBean.deblst}"  
                paginator="true"
                rows="8"
                selection="#{tableBean.selectedRec}"
                rowSelectListener="#{tableBean.onRowSelect}"   
                update="debAccTable"
                selectionMode="single"
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="8,15,20"

                >



                <p:column>

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Kunnr" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.debitorPK.kunnr}"/>
                </p:column>   

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="SAP gelöscht"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.loevm}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name1"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.name1}"/>
                </p:column>  

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name2"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.name2}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Name3"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.name3}"/>
                </p:column> 

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_ort01}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.ort01}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_pstlz}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.pstlz}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_smtpaddr}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.smtpaddr}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_stras}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.stras}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_land1}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.land1.country}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_telf1}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.telf1}"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebitorTitle_telfx}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.telfx}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Hauptzielgruppe"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.brsch.maintarget}"/>
                </p:column>
                 <p:column >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Unterzielgruppe"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debitors.brsch.subtarget}"/>
                </p:column>




                <p:column>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="actions" id="buttonPanel">  

                      <p:commandButton id="insertbutton" update=":form:display" value="Insert" title="Insert"> 
                 </p:commandButton>  
                        <p:commandButton disabled="#{tableBean.isButtonDisabled}" id="var22" update=":form:display" value="Update" title="Update"> 
                 </p:commandButton>  
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                </p:column> 

            </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>  

          <div style="background-color:#D01C2E; width:100%; height:12px;"></div>

            <p:panel header="Related Accounts">    
                 <p:dataTable id="debAccTable"                
                var="debAcc" 
                rows="5"
                paginator="true"
                update="debTable"
                value="#{tableBean.debAcclst}"
                selection="#{tableBean.selectedAccRec}"
                rowSelectListener="#{tableBean.onDecAccSelect}"  
                selectionMode="single"          
                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                rowsPerPageTemplate="3,5,10"
                 >                
        <p:column selectionMode="single">


            </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_id_row_id}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.id.row_id}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_accountname}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.accountname}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_streetaddress}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.streetaddress}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_odkundennummer}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.odkundennummer}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_plz}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.plz}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_city}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.city}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_name2}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.name2}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_name3}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.name3}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_hauptzielgruppe}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.hauptzielgruppe}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_unterzielgruppe}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.unterzielgruppe}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_email}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.email}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_tel}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.tel}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_saploeschen}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.saploeschen}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_fax}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.fax}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bundle.ListDebAccTitle_deb}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{debAcc.deb}"/>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable> 
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I dont think you will need the Tablebean as the logic behind everything is working fine its just display problems and XHTML properties. However if required i will provide. Also take note that in the XHTML im currently messing around with a lot of things so there may be some redundant stuff in there.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of primefaces are you using?

1) I'm on **PrimeFaces 3.0** at the moment and I am pretty sure that each table cell renders a unique ID. Elements inside table cells should therefore obtain unique IDs, too. I guess your problem is that you need to know the ID of the button in order to update its state. I guess the easiest way is to update the whole datatable component instead of updating the button. You might consider having a look at the Input and Output facets that have been added to datatables: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableEditing.jsf

2) Seems to be a matter of CSS to me. Have you tried applying your own style to the CSS class `ui-state-highlight`? You can use tools like Firebug in order to find out, why your styles are not applied. Perhaps you need to make some rules `!important`.

3) I'm not sure what you mean by 'zooming in on the table'. But I guess applying your own CSS styles to the table might be way to work around your problem.

Good luck .-)